# Svg animation that starts on hover doesn't play when the svg is loaded using image tag

Tags: svg, css-animations

I have the following animation:

https://svgur.com/i/6XH.svg

If you click on the link, you will see that it starts playing once you hover it.

However, when I load the svg on a page using the image tag, as done below, the hover event doesn't seem to reach the svg image.

[image]

Is it possible to do this somehow? It is not an option to paste the svg directly in the html page, because the software I use don't allow for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images by design do not expose a DOM and their content cannot receive mouse events; the target of the hover event is the `<img>` element itself. You can use an `<object>` or an `<iframe>` tag instead. The SVG is then inserted as a subdocument that users can interact with.

```html
<object data="https://svgur.com/i/6XH.svg" width="322px" height="65px"></object>
```

Comment: btw am I right to say that once SVG is inserted into img tag it sort of becomes a "raster" image as if we would draw SVG into html canvas and hence all the scripting is no longer viable?

Comment: Not completely. If the image has animations that do not depend on user interaction, [they will still run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050871/css-animation-do-not-work-for-svg-in-img). You can even trigger something from outside [via an image swap/reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215274/svg-animations-wont-work-after-import-as-a-background-image/27215399#27215399).